# In IE8 & IE9, my page is misaligned to the left. Anyone able to take a look and let me know why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

In IE8 & IE9, my page is misaligned way to the left. Anyone able to take a look and let me know why?

http://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com/SimpleProduct.aspx?p=APF800

[image: Screenshot of page in IE 8]

Looks perfect in Chrome, of course.

I wish I could provide more details, but I really am just stumped beyond belief. It's been a long time since I've been stumped this bad. :/

Comment: Looks the same to me in IE8-10. Could you perhaps post a screenshot of the behavior you're describing?

Comment: [42 Errors, 10 warning(s)](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com%2FSimpleProduct.aspx%3Fp%3DAPF800&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: Here is IE8:
http://i.imgur.com/GkdHtOa.png

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest the `<form>` tag in HTML. IE8 + IE9 will render the HTML as best as it can, but will break if you are trying to next forms. Other browsers will not do this.

I would suggest that you remove the nested forms and rework your layout accordingly.